# Android - Alert Dialog with changeable image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-alertdialog

I want to display an AlertDialog with an image. But the image may change depending on some circumstances.

This is the code I'm using for the AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(wheel.this);
                    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(wheel.this);
                    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert, null);
                    alertadd.setView(view);
                    alertadd.setTitle("Alert Dialog Title");
                    alertadd.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

                        }
                    });

                    alertadd.show();
```

And this is the alert.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to programmatically access the imageView within the XML file so I can change the image? Or is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference of `ImageView` by calling `findViewById` on your `view` and then call `setImageResource` on it :

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(wheel.this);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert, null);

// change the ImageView image source
final ImageView dialogImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
dialogImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);    

alertadd.setView(view);
alertadd.setTitle("Alert Dialog Title");
alertadd.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

        }
    });

alertadd.show();
```